# Spring Boot application: Splitting application into seperate tasks to be run from command line?

Tags: java, spring, methods, spring-boot, spring-batch

Within my `Spring boot application` I currently run it using the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("my.packages.to.scan")
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SpringApplication.run(Scheduler.class, args);
    }
}
```

This then finds the following class to run:

```
@Component
public class MyApplication {

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 400000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void tasks() {

        methodOne();
        methodTwo();
        methodThree();
    }

    public void methodOne() {

    }

    public void methodTwo() {

    }

    public void methodthree() {

    }

}
```

As can be seen from the above, my application runs all *three methods in sequence*.

I would like to *change* my application so **any** method/task can be run from the command line at any time, rather than calling the main method and running all three methods in a row.

How can I do so? Do I need to move my methods from the MyApplication class?

Comment: Do you want to be able to run the tasks during runtime of the application or only as an argument on the commandline when you start it?

Comment: I want them to be able to be run as an argument on the cmd line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to look into project [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-batch-intro). That project is exactly for such requirements. Especially [this section of its docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#runningJobsFromCommandLine) may be of your interest. It describes how can be spring batch jobs executed from command line.

**Reaction on comment:**
[Here is my Github repository with working example](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/09-batch/0910-job-parameters-cli). Notice shell scripts as examples how to execute certain tasks from command line.

Comment: Ok, is there not an easy way using java that I can configure my application to be able to call each method individually?

Comment: Yes, there is! Take a look at JMX

Comment: Im looking at it now, can you please give an example of how I would use it?